# Play Audio in Flutter from URL

Tags: android, flutter, url, audio, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and I want to play audio file from URL path with play, pause and seek button and also show notification in player.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) package.

Define `AudioPlayer` instance like this

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
```

Play audio as shown below

```
  play() async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);
    if (result == 1) {
      // success
    }
  }
```

You can pause and stop like this

```
await audioPlayer.pause();
await audioPlayer.stop();
```

This is how you can play local audio

```
 playLocal() async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(localPath, isLocal: true);
  }
```

I recommend you to use [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package. This is highly customizable with notification and you can also play audio in background or sleep mode.

Comment: Hi it is working in Emulator perfectly but when I built a APK and tried to install and run from mobile, sound not working(Not able hear sound).

Comment: @Hemal Moradiya seek bar position not changing while playing an 'http' url link.Any solution for http links??

Answer (score 4):

You can play a URL in just_audio like this:

```dart
final player = AudioPlayer();
await player.setUrl('https://example.com/song.mp3');
player.play();
player.pause();
player.seek(Duration(seconds: 143);
```

To add notification support, the easiest way is to add just_audio_background. You need to change the above code slightly so that instead of calling `setUrl`, you now do this:

```dart
await player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(
  'https://example.com/song.mp3',
  tag: MediaItem(
    id: 'Some unique ID',
    title: 'Song title',
    album: 'Song album',
    artUri: Uri.parse('https://example.com/art.jpg'),
  ),
));
```

Now once that song starts playing, the supplied metadata will also be shown in the notification.

just_audio_background must also be initialised in your main:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  await JustAudioBackground.init(/* See API for options */);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And don't forget to follow the platform-specific setup instructions for each plugin:

- [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)
- [just_audio_background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background)

Note that just_audio_background uses the audio_service plugin under the hood, so if your app has more complex requirements, you could use that plugin directly.

If you have questions about how to build the actual UI, you can create a separate question on that, or you can look at the above two links because each plugin includes an example app which demonstrates how to link it all up in a UI.

Comment: seek bar position not changing while playing an 'http' url link.Any solution for http links??

Comment: For bugs, you can report them to the GitHub page.

Comment: positionData?.duration returns zero for the http urls, that's the reason for the issue

Comment: StreamBuilder<PositionData>(
            stream: _positionDataStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final positionData = snapshot.data;
              return SeekBar(
                duration: positionData?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
                position: positionData?.position ?? Duration.zero,
                bufferedPosition: positionData?.bufferedPosition ?? Duration.zero,
                onChangeEnd: _player.seek,
              );
            },
          )

Answer (score 1):

**Open AndroidManifest.xml file and enable internet permission ,usesCleartextTraffic**

```
android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

> Add following 2 lines for enabling internet permission and usesCleartextTraffic

[image: screenshot of manifest.xml file]

Answer (score 1):

#2022 Update

After trying the above answers, i was getting this error:

**Error: Expected a value of type 'Source', but got one of type 'string'**

Here is how i managed to solve it:

Declare a variable of type Source

```
AudioPlayer myAudioPlayer=AudioPlayer();
late Source audioUrl;
```

Then initialize it in initstate()

```
audioUrl=UrlSource('https://dummyurl.com/audio1.mp3');
```

and then you can use it to play audio like this Now play it

```
myAudioPlayer.play(audioUrl);
```

Comment: have you done this player ?

Comment: yeah, it worked really fine

Comment: can u help me on this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74485490/5197712

Comment: @SaqibWani  seek bar position not changing while playing an 'http' url link.Any solution for http links??