# Flutter audioplayers returns wrong playing time?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, flutter-audioplayers

I'm using  `audioplayers: 1.1.0` plugin to play audio from url. It's playing well. But the `player.onPositionChanged` after particular seconds it restarts and timer starts from 0.
So that my slider again starts from 0.

```
  player.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
      prints(newPosition);
  });
```

Output:

```
0:00:00.000000
0:00:00.002000
0:00:00.203000
0:00:00.405000
0:00:00.607000
0:00:00.810000
0:00:01.013000
0:00:01.215000
0:00:02.027000
0:00:02.232000
0:00:03.863000
0:00:04.882000
0:00:00.236000  // after some seconds again returns from 0
0:00:00.438000
0:00:00.641000
0:00:01.052000
0:00:01.662000
0:00:01.864000
```

As this function returns again from 0, Slider also restarting as below

[image]

**This is the entire code**

> audioplayers: 1.1.0

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Audio Player'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;
  Duration duration = Duration.zero;
  Duration position = Duration.zero;

  String formatTime(int seconds) {
    return '${(Duration(seconds: seconds))}'.split('.')[0].padLeft(8, '0');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    player.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = state == PlayerState.playing;
      });
    });

    player.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        duration = newDuration;
      });
    });

    player.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
      setState(() {
        position = newPosition;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Slider(
              min: 0,
              max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
              value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                final position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                player.seek(position);
                player.resume();
              },
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (isPlaying) {
                        player.pause();
                      } else {
                      player.play("https://www.kozco.com/tech/LRMonoPhase4.mp3");
                     }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
                    onPressed: () {
                      player.stop();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(formatTime(position.inSeconds)),
                  Text(formatTime((duration - position).inSeconds)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My current version is `audioplayers: ^5.2.0`. Reference this question at the official package repository in a related issue thread: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1324